# React native async/await do not work, strange behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, fetch

I have the function CalcDistanceBetweenGoogle, which makes a fetch, passing the coordinates "to" and "from", should return the distance between the two coordinates.

If the distance is less than 20000 (20 km), then it is inserted into the array.

But it does not work properly, it is printed later.

What am I doing wrong?

Expo example: https://snack.expo.io/H1NianjoG

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.calc();
  }

  calc() {
    var markers = [
      {
        id: '269849444',
        name: 'Ziano Piacentino',
        lat: 45,
        lng: 9.4,
      },
      {
        id: '649296407',
        name: 'Monte Bondone',
        lat: 46.0315,
        lng: 11.05685,
      },
      {
        id: '300151628',
        name: 'Cima Calisio',
        lat: 46.0977158258,
        lng: 11.1443512052,
      },
      {
        id: '266239592',
        name: 'Trient, Trentino-Alto Adige, Italy',
        lat: 46.0667,
        lng: 11.1333,
      },
      {
        id: '130313194355778',
        name: 'Monte Celva',
        lat: 46.0695882,
        lng: 11.1783065,
      },
      {
        id: '217942785',
        name: 'Trento, Italy',
        lat: 46.0667,
        lng: 11.1333,
      },
      {
        id: '478657266',
        name: 'Mercatino di Natale a Levico Terme città da amare',
        lat: 46.0099217576,
        lng: 11.3052625593,
      },
      {
        id: '288554028181059',
        name: 'Fontana Del Nettuno, Trento',
        lat: 46.0675553413,
        lng: 11.1213752236,
      },
      {
        id: '252747884',
        name: 'Duomo di Milano - Milan Cathedral',
        lat: 45.4646680426,
        lng: 9.1904055604,
      },
      {
        id: '213183830',
        name: 'Piacenza',
        lat: 45.0167,
        lng: 9.66667,
      },
      {
        id: '213183830',
        name: 'Home',
        lat: 45.0167,
        lng: 9.66667,
      },
    ];

    var group = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var array = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
          var ci = markers[i];
          var cj = markers[j];
          this.CalcDistanceBetweenGoogle(ci, cj).then(async el => {
            if (el.dist <= 20000) {
              console.log(el)
              array.push(el.to);
            }
          });
        }
      }
      group.push(array);
    }
    console.log(group);
  }

  async CalcDistanceBetweenGoogle(from, to) {
    var lat1 = from.lat, lon1 = from.lng, lat2 = to.lat, lon2 = to.lng;
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' +
          lat1 +
          ',' +
          lon1 +
          '&destinations=' +
          lat2 +
          ',' +
          lon2 +
          '&mode=driving&language=it-IT',
        {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      return {
        from: from,
        to: to,
        dist: json.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <View style={styles.container} />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 80,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, declare `calc` as `async`

```
async calc()
```

Then inside the nested loop, while calling `CalcDistanceBetweenGoogle`, wait for the response using `await`.

```
const el = await this.CalcDistanceBetweenGoogle(ci, cj);
if (el.dist <= 20000) {
    console.log(el);
    array.push(el.to);
}
```

I made these changes only and `group` array populated with values, although few indices were blank.

Comment: Thx, one last thing.
I have the same call in a forEach, but it does not seem to work, I did something like this:
a.forEach (async or => {const el = await this.CalcDistanceBetweenGoogle (center, o); ...}); What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's very hard to judge the wrong statement without seeing it. If you can share your code it might help. BTW if the above statement is what you have written then, you made the spelling mistake while calling `this.CalcDistanceBetweenGoogle`, you have put `o` instead of `or`.